# Is it too much to ask for UTF-8 and correct sorting of national characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I recently switched to utf8_general_ci because it supports all character so that other people from other countries could write for example comments on my webpage.

Now, when I try to sort based on those characters, it doesn't work. For instance it is treating ö and o like the same. It's treating å and a like the same. Is it too much to ask for  both the UTF8 and correct sorting? Would it put much stress on PHP to sort a recordset of 700 records?

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: sorting 700 records in php will not be an issue, if you are not doing it frequently. otherwise it will be better if you find a good way in mysql itself

Comment: Why do you need to alphabetically sort webpage comments?  700 is a small number of records to sort w PHP, but if they share a lot of really long common prefixes it might take a while... I doubt it though.

Comment: I'm talking generally sorting here. For instance I sort all the states (not the US.) in alphabetical order to be sent to a select-list on forms. There are many times where I need sorting. But sorting after numbers doesn't solve it. For instance sorting articles alphabetically etc..

Comment: What is correct sorting for you? AFAIK in English o and ö are equivalent, while in Swedish and Finnish ö is the last letter of the alphabet and is put after z. In Spanish ñ is a letter between N and O (nz < ña), in other languages it's equivalent to N (ña < nz).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use any collation you want while sorting

```
order by some_column collate utf8_bin
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2386/4)

Comment: but will this keep the proper association of all  character

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-sets.html):

> To further illustrate, the following equalities hold in both `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci` (for the effect this has in comparisons or when doing searches, see [Section 10.1.7.8, “Examples of the Effect of Collation”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collation-effect.html)):
>
> ```
> Ä = A
> Ö = O
> Ü = U
> ```

If you want to order by *Unicode codepoint*, you should use a `xxx_bin` collation:

```
ORDER BY myColumn COLLATE utf8_bin
```

If you want to order by the string's binary encoding (which happens to produce the same result for UTF-8), you should use `BINARY`:

```
ORDER BY BINARY myColumn
```

If you want some other ordering, you will either need to identify a [pre-defined collation](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/) that meets your needs, or else [specify your own](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/adding-collation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could add another field type int wherr you put a number needed fo sort the recordeset (each firet char corresponds to a number)

Anyway 700 records are sorted with PHP in microseconds...

Comment: I'm talking generally sorting here. For instance I sort all the states (not the US.) in alphabetical order to be sent to a select-list on forms. There are many times where I need sorting. But sorting after numbers doesn't solve it. For instance sorting articles alphabetically etc..

Comment: You take the first chars of your article for example `A` and you put the corrisponding number into the field in this case `1`. The second record with first char `B` will have the field with `2`. So you just need to `ORDER BY numberField`

Comment: But isn't that really unneccecary? Isn't it better to modify a character set in that case? I solved this using a language-specific encoding for some cases, and utf8_bin for binary comparisons :)

Comment: This was a possible solution, you can use any other solution